# SQL to query rows from parent tables with two child tables, with blank values if no child row exists

Tags: sql, join

I have three tables, a parent and two children, the two children have FK releationship to the parent using an ID column, and there may be 0 to n child rows for each parent row.  I need to produce a query that will generate a single result set of data from all three tables.

If the child row doesn't exist, the fields for that table should just be blank, otherwise, these fields should have the appropriate values.

```
Table A     Table B           Table C
--------    -------           -------
ID (PK)     A_ID (FK)         A_ID (FK)
DataA1       DataB1            DataC1
DataA2       DataB2            DataC2
```

This query:

```
select * from A,B,C where A.ID = B.A_ID and A.ID = C.A_ID
```

will return only rows from A where both child rows B and C exist.  I want to return rows from A where either child row B or child row C exists for A.ID.  If no row for B exists, B.DataB1 and B.DataB2 should be null or blank, and similarly if no row for C exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an outer join.

```
select
    A.ID,
    A.DataA1,
    A.DataA2,
    B.A_ID,
    B.DataB1,
    B.DataB2,
    C.A_ID,
    C.DataC1,
    C.DataC2
from A 
left join B
on A.ID = B.A_ID
left join C
on A.ID = C.A_ID
```

For a good explanation of SQL joins checkout: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html